Expected an int but was 68.85670471
Hello friends can u help me with this problem ?
I have declared it in the manifest from which activity to which i am sending the data.I checked similar posts like How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?
But it does not help.
The class i am sending data:

The receiving class:

Logcat :


"Expected an int but was 68.85670471" 68.85670471 isn't an int. It's a float or a double. There are also methods like Float parseFloat().

"the receiving has no parsed id." Your debugger has stopped on a line that would write a value to id. That line of code hasn't run yet, so of course id is 0. You need to check the debugger after that line of code has run. But as the question said (before the last edit that probably shouldn't have been done) the code crashes with a NumberFormatException because the Intent String extra is not an integer.

Thanks for the response tried and change all the places(methods) where it says int but it gives me more bad error that it does not tell me what is wrong with app in the bottom of the screen.

I had put List instead of ArrayList in my WinePairing Class.
